# Plotly: How to add a text box under legend?

Tags: python, textbox, plotly, legend, plotly-express

I use this example code given in plotly website.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.medals_long()

fig = px.bar(df, x="medal", y="count", color="nation",
             pattern_shape="nation", pattern_shape_sequence=[".", "x", "+"])
fig.show()
```

This gives a plot like below.
[image]

**How can I add a text box under the legend in the plot to get it like in the picture below?**
[image]

**I see some examples using [Text and Annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#:%7E:text=Canadian%20cities-,Positioning%20Text%20Annotations%20Absolutely,-By%20default%2C%20text) but was wondering if there is any other approach to do it.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I could find, adding an annotation is the only way to get the expected output natively in plotly.

An implemntation of the annotation will look like:

```
fig.add_annotation(text='South Korea: Asia <br>China: Asia <br>Canada: North America', 
                    align='left',
                    showarrow=False,
                    xref='paper',
                    yref='paper',
                    x=1.1,
                    y=0.8,
                    bordercolor='black',
                    borderwidth=1)
```

Some additional html attributes you can add to the text attribute be found here: https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/adding-HTML-and-links-to-charts/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer.

For me setting `x=1.1` didn't directly put the text box on the same vertical line under the legend.

[text not on the same line with legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz6N1.png)

My legend settings:

```
{
  orientation="v",
  y=1,
  x=1,
}
```

However, setting **`xanchor="left"`** and `x=1` for annotation made both legend and text appear on the same vertical line. So my total annotations config is:

```
fig.add_annotation(
    text="Some<br>multi-line<br>text",
    align="left",
    showarrow=False,
    xref="paper",
    yref="paper",
    font=dict(color="white", size=9),
    bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    y=0.2,
    x=1,
    xanchor="left",
)
```

Suppose this is because default `xanchor` value for legend if `left` ([docs](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-legend-xanchor)) while for annotations it is `auto` ([docs](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/annotations/#layout-annotations-items-annotation-xanchor))